# How to find unique couples in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I'm inserting these documents:

```
db.users.insert({user1: 'a',user2: 'b'});
db.users.insert({user1: 'b',user2: 'a'});
db.users.insert({user1: 'c',user2: 'd'});
db.users.insert({user1: 'd',user2: 'c'});
```

Please note that user1 and user2 are actually ObjectId, but I'm writing them as single char to better explain the issue.

I need to select unique rows, where unicity is given by the couple, i.e. two users are connected to each other.
So in the inserts above Im creating 2 unique couples/pairs:

```
user 'A' paired with user 'B' 
user 'C' paired with user 'D'
```

Is it possible to accomplish this directly in mongo or do I need some algorithm in my code (javascript)?

The final result should be

```
[
    {user1: 'A',user2: 'B'}
    ,{user1: 'C',user2: 'D'}
]
```

This would also work:

```
[
    {user1: 'B',user2: 'A'}
    ,{user1: 'D',user2: 'C'}
]
```

Comment: does it better if you create a new collection like `relation`, where inside will be like `{ _id: ObjectId(), users: [userId]` ? by this way you can get easier their relationship.

Comment: Do you need both `{user1: 'a',user2: 'b'}` **_and_** `{user1: 'b',user2: 'a'}` for `a` and `b` to be a _"unique couple"_?

Comment: Yes, both shoud be there: {user1: a, user2: b} and {user1: b, user2: a}

Comment: I do not understand why you want to have two documents for only one relation, Tobok suggestion is good for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregation pipeline. It groups documents by pair of users and uses `$cond` to ensure that the order of the users doesn't matter.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $cond: [
          { $gt: [ "$user1", "$user2" ] },
          { user1: "$user1", user2: "$user2" },
          { user1: "$user2", user2: "$user1" }
        ]
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      user1: "$_id.user1",
      user2: "$_id.user2"
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/8FLUiMDkG85

Answer (score 1):

Without much consideration for special case like only 1 directed relation / more than 2 directed relations(i.e. expected always 2 relations for certain couple). You can simply `$group` by `$setUnion` of 2 users and pick the first doc.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "$setUnion": [
          [
            "$user1"
          ],
          [
            "$user2"
          ]
        ]
      },
      doc: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KHOtm8bVriR)